# Ionic storage set method

Tags: ionic-framework, storage

I have and project in ionic 5, i am using ionic storage module in it. But when i try to save key-value, it is not saving any value not giving any error.

```
this.storage.set('name', 'Michael');

this.storage.get('name').then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

Comment: Hi!,can you provide a look of your app module?

Comment: Do you run these two code same time like this you write in question?